# DHCP with SOHO Routers turned off with DHCP Server

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I am trying to learn some networking right now. I currently have a DHCP service running on my SOHO CISCO Router. If I turn off my SOHO's DHCP service and setup DHCP on a physical computer/machine/server (say my computer with an I7 processor), will my clients still receive an IP Address? The DHCP computer is directly connected to the LAN of this router. Will also my router become now a simple router and switch without doing DHCP?

Comment: I do not think so, they connect via the router, not the computer. Unless a certain scenario pops up, it will most likely not happen.

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013, please don't speculate.  This scenario should work just fine.  The router is not doing anything special on the LAN.  Any node on the LAN can host a DHCP server and serve requests.  Its actually very common in large networks where there is a dedicated router and a separate dedicated DHCP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DHCP requests are sent out as broadcast packets that can be heard by any other machine in the same network broadcast domain (i.e. within the same switched segment).
Who answeres them is unimportant as long as the right configuration is delivered.